# React JS: "Error: ningún archivo encontrado" al intentar descargar PDF

Tags: reactjs

Estimados su apoyo por favor estoy usando el atributo download para descargar un archivo pdf, pero la descargar me indica Error: ningún archivo encontrado.

tengo 2 componentes, no se se si un problema de permisos o headers. alguna sugerencia.

```js
import React from "react";

class DownloadLink extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <a href={this.props.src} download target="_blank">
        {this.props.children}
      </a>
    );
  }
}

export default DownloadLink;



import React, { Component } from "react";
    import DownloadLink from '../DownloadLink'

    class contentOnDesktop extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="contentOnDesktop">
          
    <DownloadLink src="../pdf/manual_de_uso.pdf">DESCARGAR</DownloadLink>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default contentOnDesktop;
```

Comment: Estas seguro de la ruta? Y si pruebas realizando un `import` del archivo?

Comment: importo el archivo, en cual componente el de download?

Answer (score 0):

esta linea esta diciendo que en el árbol del proyecto de la ruta base estas subiendo un nivel para ir a buscar DownloadLink, ¿eso es correcto?

```
import DownloadLink from '../DownloadLink'
```

luego

```
src="../pdf/manual_de_uso.pdf"
```

estas subiendo un nivel a la carpeta "/pdf"

puedes situarte en la base del proyecto con  `./` y luego navegar entre las carpetas.

Comment: si, si muevo los niveles me dice error al compilar... en ambos casos

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCION:

```js
import React from "react";
import pdf from './pdf/manual_de_uso.pdf'


class DownloadLink extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <a href={pdf} download target="_blank">
        {this.props.children}
      </a>
    );
  }
}

export default DownloadLink;



import React, { Component } from "react";
    import DownloadLink from '../DownloadLink'

    class contentOnDesktop extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="contentOnDesktop">
          
    <DownloadLink href={this.props.pdf}>DESCARGAR</DownloadLink>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default contentOnDesktop;
```